# How do I stop this from exiting after the first iteration?

Tags: python, loops, replace, iteration

I'm trying to return a statement that replaces given old characters with new characters, but the loop keeps exiting after the first iteration.

```
def test(s, old_ch, new_ch): 
    """returns the given input and replaces an old character with a new character""" 
    newstring = "" 
    for ch in s: 
        while (ch == old_ch): 
            newstring += new_ch  
            break
        while (ch != old_ch):
            newstring += ch 
            break 
        return newstring
```

I know that there are already defined replace functions in python, but this is the way I've been told to do it. (same with the `for ch in s` bits)

Comment: `return newstring` shouldn't be in the iteration. Remove a level of indentation.

Comment: A `while` loop that immediately breaks is the same as an `if` statement.

Comment: So those two `while` loops should just be `if` and `else`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to change.

1. Instead of using a while-loop and breaking, just use an if-statement. Your code will still work the same way, but it'll be much more readable.
2. Move the return statement outside of the for-loop, i.e. unindent it. This way `newstring` won't be returned until the entire for-loop has been executed, which is the desired behavior.

The full corrected code is below:

```py
def test(s, old_ch, new_ch): 
    """returns the given input and replaces an old character with a new character""" 
    newstring = "" 
    for ch in s: 
        if (ch == old_ch): 
            newstring += new_ch  
        else:
            newstring += ch 
    return newstring

print(test("Megalovania", "a", "o"))
# Prints Megolovonio
```

Comment: @user15261256 If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. This tells others that the issue is resolved and helps people find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

`for ch in s` statement is used to loop over every character of the string.
Hence the while loop inside the for loop is not required.

```
def test(s, old_ch, new_ch): 
    """returns the given input and replaces an old character with a new character""" 
    newstring = "" 
    for ch in s: 
        if(ch == old_ch): 
            newstring = newstring+new_ch  
            
        if(ch != old_ch):
            newstring = newstring + ch 
            
    return newstring
```

This code does the intended work you want to achieve.

Comment: You didn't mention that you also need to unindent the return statement.

Comment: Thanks @M-Chen-3 for pointing out, I forgot to mention that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, so that you will get a better understanding of the iteration.

```
def test(s, old_ch, new_ch): 
    newstring = "" 
    for ch in s:
        print(f"ch is {ch}")
        if (ch == old_ch):
            print(f"if condition is True for ch {ch} and old_ch {old_ch}")
            newstring += new_ch  
        else:
            print(f"elif condition is True for ch {ch} and old_ch {old_ch}")
            newstring += ch
    print(newstring)
    return newstring
```

call this function

```
test("New to Python", "t", "y")
```

Output is

```
ch is N
elif condition is True for ch N and old_ch t
ch is e
elif condition is True for ch e and old_ch t
ch is w
elif condition is True for ch w and old_ch t
ch is  
elif condition is True for ch   and old_ch t
ch is t
if condition is True for ch t and old_ch t
ch is o
elif condition is True for ch o and old_ch t
ch is  
elif condition is True for ch   and old_ch t
ch is P
elif condition is True for ch P and old_ch t
ch is y
elif condition is True for ch y and old_ch t
ch is t
if condition is True for ch t and old_ch t
ch is h
elif condition is True for ch h and old_ch t
ch is o
elif condition is True for ch o and old_ch t
ch is n
elif condition is True for ch n and old_ch t
```

Comment: Those print statements are entirely unnecessary. Stack Overflow is not meant to replace a Python tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I agreed but for beginners, I think it will be more useful.